# Exposing typescript function for consuming html page to call

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, parceljs

I am currently writing a typescript modular library that is parcelled with parcel js. This library will be consumed by applications for specific functionality. The consuming application/web page will add reference in its html to my library eg.

```
<script defer src='mylib.js' />
```

I want to expose a single function in my library for the consumers to call and initialise my library. What is the best way to expose this one function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use service/provider concept. However creating service u need singleton object. JS it is tough to do. I have read few article how to create singleton. Below give sample can match ur requirement.

```js
const singleton = clName => {
  return new Proxy(clName.prototype.constructor, {
    inst: null,
    construct: (target, args) => {
      if (!this.inst) this.inst = new target(...args);
      return this.inst;
    }
  });
};
class Util {
  constructor(configs) {
    this.time = +new Date();
    this.configs = configs;
  }
  printMsg() {
    console.log(this.msg);
  }
}

UtilClass = singleton(Util);

const myObj = new UtilClass({ timeout: 100 });
console.log(myObj)
const myObj2 = new UtilClass({ timeout: 200 });
console.log(myObj2)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; color: blue; background: #fff}
```